# Extracting DOM elements data using regex on the raw CSS

Tags: css, regex

I need to retrieve all CSS applied to a element. The problem is that the dom tree may be long or not. I want a regex that will match all the css rules that may contain the relevant html tags, regardsless of their classes or ids.

I tried using the following:

```
/(section.class\s*h1\s*a)/gm
```

The elements would be:

```
<a class="first">
<h1>
<section id="myId">
```

I want something to math all the possibilities

```
section h1 a

section#myId h1 a

section#myId h1 a.first

section h1 a.first
```

Something that will find the html tag, and will find with and without the classes and ids.

Comment: No problem, do you have a fixed list of tag names ?

Comment: Btw, the default of with and without  is tag + "I don't care, any or no attribute/value is ok".

Comment: the value can be changed, the problem is matching a element with or without classes and id, something like Element (Class, ID)

Comment: Thas what I meant, with an without  = `(?si)</?(?:section|h1|a)\b(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]?)+>` matchs both _with_ and _without_.

Comment: Here it is where both are required = `(?si)<(?:section|h1|a)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?(?<=\s)CLASS\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*((?:(?!\1).)*?)\s*\1))(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?(?<=\s)ID\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*((?:(?!\3).)*?)\s*\3))\s+(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+>`

Comment: Here it is with one or the other required = `(?si)<(?:section|h1|a)(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?(?<=\s)(CLASS|ID)\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*((?:(?!\2).)*?)\s*\2))\s+(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+>`

Comment: the search will be performed on a .css file

Comment: Here it is where CLASS and ID are optionally matched, but not required along with any closing tags. I believe this is the one you want. Make a template out of it. Us another regex to parse your rules so that you may construct this $500 regex I'm letting you use:  `(?si)</?(?:section|h1|a)\b(?:(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?(?<=\s)CLASS\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*((?:(?!\1).)*?)\s*\1)))?(?:(?=(?:[^>"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*?(?<=\s)ID\s*=\s*(?:(['"])\s*((?:(?!\3).)*?)\s*\3)))?\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^>]*?)+>`